# Unexplainable crash error

Tags: android

My app crashes when I try to run it. I don't know what could be causing this error... It might be related to my previous question but that post wasn't very good so I'll post the new error here.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapp, PID: 12693
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field AppCompatTheme of type [I in class Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable; or its superclasses (declaration of 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable' appears in /data/data/com.myapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4_13f90a0ab4d497a8a87e7463d225d6b3993606ba-classes.dex)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:336)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:309)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:273)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
  at com.myapp.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2855)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

I can't find any information on this error anywhere else, which is really weird.

Comment: May seem dumb, but did you clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: Yes, I cleaned and rebuilt the project and the error's still there.

Comment: Uninstalling the app from the testing device and rerunning it fixed the error... for now... This isn't the first time it's disappeared and later reemerged, though.

Comment: I experienced this problem immediately after upgrading from support library version 23.1.1 to 23.2.1.  The problem was resolved by a clean and rebuild.

Comment: Yes, clean and rebuild helps.

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to this error now when upgrading my build tools from 23.0.1 to 23.0.2. I spent an hour investigating how I can solve this problem (I did several cleans and rebuilds and none worked).

Eventually, I took 19lymers advice and deleted the app and reinstalled it and then it got fixed.

**EDITED:**

I don't know whether this is also related or not but before I did the deletion, my app was already buggy - icons which were suppose to be displayed in one location ended up displaying in another location. I think the resource.xml got corrupted. When that happens, best to delete and reinstall. That's the quickest way to solve this issue.